# How to build Custom sorting logic in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a column in a table which will have numeric number for custom sort.
This column will then be used to sort in a specific order in view code in Snowflake

Input table

[image]

If the employee has role "Insights Manager" / "Executive Manager", the order of sort will always be "1" , for rest of the roles, it can have alphabetical order.

The number of roles one employee has will be dynamic, few may have 2 roles only, few may have 8 roles as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this

```
select 
emp_id,role,
row_number() over (partition by emp_id order by DECODE (role, 'Insights Manager', '1' ,'Executive Manager','2' ,role))  custom_order
from mytable
order by custom_order
```

First character will ensure managers will stay on top.

EDIT : This field will give you sequence number in a new column and then order by that.
First case - Insight manager will always be 1, Executive Manager will be 2 and then rest will be 3,4 etc.
Second case -In case Insight manager is absent, then Executive Manager will be 1 and then rest will be 2,3,4 etc.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. However, I need to have column with the orders like 1,2,3,4,5 etc. This derived column I then need to use in another logic.

Comment: could you pls refer to modified answer

Comment: Thank you for modified one, I tried with partition by EMPId, now if there is a EMP with both roles, it is coming in Executive Manager first and then Insights Manager, I want like this : If one employee has BOTH the roles "Insights Manager" and "Executive Manager", then "Insights Manager" should be the first one in order and then rest. If one employee has ONLY "Insights Manager", then this will come first and then the rest. If one employee has ONLY "Executive Manager", then this would come first and then rest.

Comment: got it. corrected again,

Comment: Thank you for the modified one, question : Third case -In case Executive manager is absent, then will Insight Manager be 1 and then rest will be 2,3,4 etc ? As well

Comment: yes, if exec manager is absent then, insight Manager be 1 and rest will be 2,3,4